# How can I find the mp3/aac files of net radio stations so I can play them in other programs such as alarm clocks or calendars?

Tags: audio, mp3, calendar

For instance, if I went to shoutcast, how could I get the .mp3 or .aac or .whatever so I can paste it into an alarm program for playback as an alarm clock radio?

In other words, how can I find the direct link to a particular song from a streaming service, so that my device will play it on-demand.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Network radio is streaming service - they don't download whole files to Your computer before playing it.
But You could find out name of the song (Shazam ?) and than buy/download it from internet (iTunes, Amazon etc ...)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Actually, I'm not talking about downloading the files, I'm talking about streaming their mp3/aac streams. Such streams do exist.

Answer (score 0):

Shoutcast and similar services work by downloading a playlist file that contains the URL for the stream (typically, multiple URLs in case one stream server is overloaded or whatever). On Shoutcast.com specifically, you can try right-clicking the play button and saving the file (e.g., `tunein-station.pls`). Then open it up in a text editor to get the list of URLs.